# Retrieve RelayState value using Passport-SAML

Tags: passport-saml

I am unable to retrieve the RelayState value. Can someone please direct me or provide a link to relevant documentation.

This is what I have so far as my setup and routes.

**Setup**

```
const saml_strategy = new saml.Strategy(
    {
        'callbackUrl': 'https://callback-url/adfs/postResponse',
        'entryPoint': 'https://entry-url/adfs/ls/',
        'issuer': 'issuer-name',
        'decryptionPvk': fs.readFileSync('./private.key', 'utf-8'),
        'cert': [idp_cert],
        'identifierFormat': null,
   'disableRequestedAuthnContext': true,
   'authnContext': ["urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport"],
   'additionalParams':{'RelayState':'test'}
    },
```

**Routes**

```
app.get(
    '/', 
    function (req, res) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) 
        {
           res.send( '{ "authenticated": true }' );
        } 
        else 
        {
            res.send( '{ "authenticated":  false }' );
        }
    }
);

app.get(
    '/login', 
    passport.authenticate('saml', { 'successRedirect': '/', 'failureRedirect': '/login' }),
    function(req, res) 
      {
        res.redirect('/');
      }
);

///login/callback
app.post(
    '/adfs/postResponse',
    passport.authenticate('saml', { 'failureRedirect': '/', 'failureFlash': true }),
    function(req, res) 
    {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RelayState` is set from the query string of the  initial login request page, and then (provided the IdP respects it), it is available in the body of the callback POST response.

So in your case, this should work:

```js
app.get(
    '/login', 
    function(req, res, next){
        // you could redirect to /login?RelayState=whatever, or set query here,
        // the value must be encoded for passing in the query string:
        req.query.RelayState = encodeURIComponent('my relay state');
    },
    passport.authenticate('saml', { 'successRedirect': '/', 'failureRedirect': '/login' }),
    function(req, res) 
    {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
);
```

```js
app.post(
    '/adfs/postResponse',
    passport.authenticate('saml', { 'failureRedirect': '/', 'failureFlash': true }),
    function(req, res) 
    {
        console.log(`relay state was ${decodeURIComponent(req.body.RelayState)}`);
        res.redirect('/');
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you James, I will give it a try and let you know of the outcome.